# Latest Data based on DateTime or CustMCId

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table in which different Clients are assign to different MC. Like Client (84)  switch the MC 3 times. Now I want to get the latest MC of Client=84. I make this Query

```
 select max(cstmrMC.CustMCId),cstmrMC.CustId,cstmrMC.MCID,cstmrMC.AssignDate 
    from CustomerMC cstmrMC
    where cstmrMC.CustId=84
    group by cstmrMC.CustMCId,cstmrMC.CustId,cstmrMC.MCID,cstmrMC.AssignDate 
    ORDER BY cstmrMC.CustMCId,cstmrMC.CustId,cstmrMC.MCID,cstmrMC.AssignDate
```

which shows this result

```
CustMCId     CustId   MCID            AssignDate
52           84    18      2013-10-01 18:21:56.000
59           84     7      2013-09-09 16:10:06.000
80           84    19      2013-10-09 03:54:00.000
156          84    21      2013-11-11 00:00:00.000
```

NOw I want only this

```
156          84    21      2013-11-11 00:00:00.000
```

How can I get this result????

Comment: because CustId=84 latestly assing to MCID=21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the row_number function to partition and order the customers so that the most recent MCID (based on AssignDate) is first within each customer.

```
WITH cteCustomers AS (
    SELECT CustMCId, CustId, MCID, AssignDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustId ORDER BY AssignDate DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM CustomerMC
)
SELECT CustMCId, CustId, MCID, AssignDate
    FROM cteCustomers
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: Joe: show correct result but difficult to understand for me as i am beginner not a ninja :P

Comment: @AyliyaJan: The row_number function arranges your data into groups. The PARTITION BY clause says that I want each CustId treated as one grouping. The ORDER BY says that, within each CustId grouping, I want the numbers I am creating assigned based on the descending AssignDate. So, within each customer, the most recent AssignDate will be assigned the number 1. Make sense?